# Spring form validation on user defined objects

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, bean-validation

```
    i have a Employee class with the following content:

    public class Employee {

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        private String epfno;

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        private String empno;

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        private String empfullname;

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        private Address address;

       ****GETTERS AND SETTERS****

    }

    Address class class with the following content:

    public class Address {

        private int addressid;
        private Employee employee;

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        private String description;

       ****Getters and SETTERS****
    }
```

The controller  class with the following content:
  When i try to validate the address field the form actually returns a null. instead of throwing an not null error message. i did the debugging in the controller to capture it
        @RequestMapping(value = "/Form/Employee/Submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String SubmitEmployeeForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("Employee")Employee Employee,BindingResult br) {

```
        if(br.hasErrors())
        {
            logger.info("Form Validation Errors have Occured");
            return "Homepage";
        }

        else {

            // Does not through error instead sends null when field is empty 

            System.out.println(Employee.getAddress().getDescription()); // Null
            return "Homepage";
        }


    }

How can i get the address field to get populated with a not null error message instead of it passing the value null ? thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    I figured it out. after adding the @valid annotation on the address object it worked 
    fine.

        public class Employee {

        @NotNull(message="Field Cannot be Empty")
        @valid
        private Address address;

       ****GETTERS AND SETTERS****

    }
```